# Button text alignment not displayed well when using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I use one button and apply constraint, horizontal and vertical text alignment

Constraint :-

1. Top :- 0
2. Right :- 0
3. Bottom :- 0

Horizontal text alignment :- Right

Vertical text alignment :- Bottom

Current device :- iPhone 8

===============================================================

Now I just change device iPhone 8 to iPhone SE

After change device, text alignment of button changed or not display well

[image]

===============================================================

But after move button orientation button text alignment set properly

[image]

Comment: initially in which device  are  you set the Constraint for your button

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I set constraint according to iPhone 8

Comment: initally set the constraint to the minimum size of  device and check in iPhone 8  will work

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No, it's not work